# ASP C# Datalist OnItemDataBound event To Change Another Cell Contents

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, datalist

I'm fairly new to asp/c# and I'm working on a project that when runs a sql stored procedure will produce a report based on the data, and I'm populating a datalist table right now with with 'the top 5 sql records'.

I'm having an issue of accessing the datalist data and I'd like to change the aligning cell of a pulled field according to the pulled field's value.

I have a datalist setup with an OnItemBound procedure.

Page code:

```asp
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" onitemdatabound="DataList2_ItemDataBound">
            <HeaderTemplate>
             <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Certification Date</th>
                    <th colspan="2">As Found Potential</th>
                    <th>As Found Tolerance</th>
                    <th colspan="2">As Left Potential</th>
                    <th>As Left Tolerance</th>    
                </tr>
          </HeaderTemplate> 
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>                                                                
                        <td class="td04">                
                            <asp:Label ID="certificationDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("as_left_date", "{0:MM/dd/yyy}") %>' /> <!-- Certification Date Always As Left -->
                        </td>
                        <td class="td05">                
                            <asp:Label ID="asFoundPotential" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDouble(Eval("as_found_entered")) %>' /> <!-- As Found Entered -->
                        </td>
                        <td class="td06">                
                            <div>mV</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="td04">                
                            <asp:Label ID="asFoundTolerance" runat="server" Text='In Tolerance' /> <!-- ItemDataBound to Change Contents -->
                        </td>
                        <td class="td05">                
                            <asp:Label ID="asLeftPotential" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("as_left_entered") %>' /> <!-- As Left Entered -->
                        </td>
                        <td class="td06">                
                            <div>mV</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="td04">                
                            <asp:Label ID="asLeftTolerance" runat="server" Text='In Tolerance' /> <!-- ItemDataBound to Change Contents -->
                        </td>               
                    </tr>                    
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

Code Behind:

```c#
        protected void dataTable2()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Records"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("report_page", conn);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serial_number", serial_number.Text);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);

            try
            {                
                conn.Open();

                adp.Fill(ds);
                DataList2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                DataList2.DataBind();            

            }

            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                writeToFile(Environment.NewLine + "SQL DataTable2 Error: " + ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
                myCommand.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

OnDataBound event:

```c#
        protected void DataList2_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {
              //cell change code goes here
        }
```

The "In Tolerance" cell/string contents I would like to change based on the "as_found_entered" value which is a double.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    // Retrieve the Label control in the current DataListItem.
    Label asFoundPotential = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("asFoundPotential");

    // You can convert the asFoundPotential lable value in double.

    if (asFoundPotential = Something)
    {
        // identify the specific cell of asLeftPotential  and assign whatever you want to change    
    }
}
```

Hope this pseudo code will help you with what you need to put in the `ItemDataBound` event.

Comment: Thank you for this.  With this snipet, I finally got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked.  The label references are key and the label to double took a bit of messing with.

```c#
        protected void DataList2_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {                               
                Label asFoundTolerance = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("asFoundTolerance");
                Label asLeftTolerance = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("asLeftTolerance");

                Label asFoundPotential = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("asFoundPotential");
                double foundPot = Convert.ToDouble(asFoundPotential.Text);                
                if (foundPot < 305.5 || foundPot > 326.4)
                {                    
                    asFoundTolerance.Text = "Out of Tolerance";
                    be4TestG.Checked = false;
                    be4TestB.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    asFoundTolerance.Text = "In Tolerance";
                    be4TestG.Checked = true;
                    be4TestB.Checked = false;
                }

                Label asLeftPotential = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("asLeftPotential");
                double leftPot = Convert.ToDouble(asLeftPotential.Text);
                if (leftPot < 305.5 || leftPot > 326.4)
                {
                    asLeftTolerance.Text = "Out of Tolerance";
                    aftTestG.Checked = false;
                    aftTestB.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    asLeftTolerance.Text = "In Tolerance";
                    aftTestG.Checked = true;
                    aftTestB.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
```